# useEffect - state doesn't update when unmounting

Tags: reactjs

I am asking this question to understand the concept of state lifecycle. Below I have an example code:

```
  const {userId} = useParams();
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(userId)) || []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (todos.length === 0) {
      fetchUserTodos(userId).then(todo => setTodos(todo));
    }
    return () => {
      localStorage.setItem(`${userId}`, JSON.stringify(todos));
    }
  }, [])
```

I am using React Router v6 to get the userId param and trying to save it in localstorage. Right now, in the above code snippet, I am passing an empty array, which means I am only running the fetchUserTodos function once when mounting and if the condition is met. This function also sets the todos value once it fetches the data from a web server. I do have some other functions that update the todos in my UI. After I have updated the todos, the localStorage should have saved the updated todos, but it saves an empty array.

This issue was solved if I pass todos in the array, which means the localStorage is always updated when todos ischanging. But, I am wondering why is this the behavior because I was expecting that the todos state of the component was already updated before unmounting, not the initial value stored in todos. Would be nice if someone could explain this behavior and make the concept a bit clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this:

```
return () => {}
```

you are creating a stale closure. This means that in that specific time the closure captures the **todos** value of the state and it will keep that outdated value during its whole course of life. If you only need to save the value in the local storage after you fetched it than you can just add it in the .then() like this:

```
fetchUserTodos(userId).then(todo => {
 setTodos(todo);
 localStorage.setItem(`${userId}`, JSON.stringify(todo));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code if it works, I think its better to read `localStorage` data inside `useEffect`

```
const {userId} = useParams();
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    try{
         let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(userId));
         setTodos(data);
    }catch(err){
         fetchUserTodos(userId).then(todo => setTodos(todo));
    }

    return ()=>{
         localStorage.setItem(`${userId}`, JSON.stringify(todos));    
    }
},[])
```